# How to get bearer token to a aspnet razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a question about Bearer Token on asp.net WebApi. I've been creating WebApi's but just to be consumed by some client(Android,iOS), but now I need to create a Login page in this same project and I don't know how to handle this, since once using a client app, i just make a request to `api/token` and get the access token, but how to get this from a Web Page? Do I need to use some back-end like NodeJs or AngularJS ?

This is the endpoint :

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(300),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        });
```

Comment: Just make a http request to the same endpoint `api/token` and the bearer token should be returned in the headers or body depending on how you return it?

Comment: But the problem is, if I need to create more pages to pass the token through the header ? I nee to storage this somewhere on browser!  it would be more easier to do this with nodeJs ?

Comment: Not sure why you would use node?Just hold the bearer token client side in a session variable or similar, then you can use it whenever you make a request to your API. Out of interest, what are you using on the client side? JQuery? Angular? Knockout?

Comment: I'm using nothing yet. That's why I was asking how to save this token, if I should use NodeJs to request and get the token or by `HttpClient` from C#. I'm new with web-side thing. So with Angular should solve my problem ?

Comment: Essentially, whatever you use on the client side to get the token (I  use Angular and React as they have in built functionality for making http requests), you then need to get the response and store the token in the client. Take a read of this https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage. It should give you a bit of insight into client side storage. Again I tend to use cookies as it's built in with a lot of the .net MVC stuff, but you could use session storage also

Comment: Thanks man for the enlightenment man! I was completely lost! I'll read the article! Its better cu'z I wont nee to do anything with back-end itself only with Angular.!

Comment: Yes, basically. Glad to be of help. I'll drop my comment as an answer

Comment: I figured it might be worth mentioning that a popular misconception is that there is some kind of inherent synergy or even connectivity between JavaScript apps in a browser and JavaScript in NodeJS. This is very much not the case so it makes no difference what backend you use and adding a NodeJS server to your stack will actually make things much more complex at this point since you are already using ASP.NET.

Comment: @AluanHaddad got it. Besides using Angular to request this toke, what other options inside of WebApi I could accomplish this? Login,requests and post's without using Token? I found a lot of tutorials about Asp.NET Authentication but I'm not sure if is the same Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, whatever you use on the client side to get the token (I use Angular and React as they have in built functionality for making http requests), you then need to get the response and store the token in the client. Take a read of this https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage. It should give you a bit of insight into client side storage. Again I tend to use cookies as it's built in with a lot of the .net MVC stuff, but you could use session storage also